# Buttons move themselves after upgrade to Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode5

This is something that I've brushed off for a while now, but needs to be fixed. Recently, I upgraded to Xcode 5. After the upgrade, the buttons on the initial view will move after being clicked. This only affects that view, and none of the other views. This is odd, because the main view has no attached code to it - it is just a default UIViewController class. I tried creating a custom UIViewController class and linking the view to it, and I've tried deleting the button and recreating it - but they still move when clicked.  Has anyone else had this problem after they upgraded to Xcode 5?

Before I click a button

[image: Before I click a button]

[image]

And after I click a button

Answer (score 1):

I suspected the problem is with the new Auto layout and the constraints. I have had similar issues with this when an object redraws it moves. Normally mine are when I expand a NSWindow  (OSX) the objects inside its view fly off into a different position.

I would suggest you read the Documentation on [Auto Layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1) and then have a look at how your buttons are set up. The is also a section on how to debug issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely happening due to auto layout. You have two options:

- Add auto layout constraints that will position them in fixed positions, so that way they will never move.
- Disable auto layout for your storyboard or XIB that contains the view controller.